# how to use mailchimp 2.0 with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, mailchimp

I am very new to using APIs. I want to use [mailchimp 2.0](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/) with CodeIgniter. I tried to integrate mailchimp libraries but it doesn't work.

**Error**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set

Filename: libraries/Mailchimp.php

Line Number: 138


Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mailchimp::getList() in /home/dtworks/public_html/moh/ebook/application/modules/mailinglist/controllers/mailinglist.php on line 27
```

Comment: Can you turn off `safe_mode` and `open_basedir` on your host?

Comment: thank you .. i downloaded a library handle it

Comment: May I know what is the library? I am facing the same issue too

Comment: I will review it and i will respond you with its name

Comment: sorry man i didn't search it yet. do you still want it ?